# Why is this PNG showing up with a invisible background when I put a box-shadow on it?

Tags: css, png

I have the correct code.  No color added to it.  Have all my pre-fixes.  It shows up like this in any browser.  I am saving it with the correct transparency setting in PS as seen in the screen shot.  It is transparent except when I put a box-shadow around it.  What is this?

Here are some screenshots:

[image: png]

[image: png]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. The image is a square even if you have transparency. If you want a shadow on the PNG to fit the non-transparent portion, you'll have to add the shadow to the PNG itself and not use a css shadow.

In the particular scenario you're looking at (assuming that what you're trying to do is add a shadow to one of three identically shaped image tabs) you can put each tab in a div with padding where a shadow would go, create a single png with with a shadow shaped appropriately, and just have a css class that applies the shadow image as a background on the active tab.

**EDIT: Another approach?**

After I answered this I thought "could one perhaps apply styling to an image poly map, and have the shadow cast on that?". Unfortunately, the answer is no. For reasons that are beyond me, image maps can only have a small number of styles apply to them (positioning, for instance) and will never be visible. However, it did lead me down another avenue: build an image map with poly areas, and use javascript to take the coordinates and create an svg with a shadow filter on it. This svg could then be set as the background image to the frame with the transparent PNG (or positioning an otherwise tranparent svg on top of the image. This would obviously not work for all browsers as some don't support svg, but it's an interesting concept, and I might have to put together a js library for implementing it... it would certainly make applying shaped shadows easier.

Comment: This is what I was suspecting.  I was just wondering if the box-shadow property was capable of recognizing shapes created outside of css.  Now I know.  I like your solution as it should shave a little file size as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The shadow is applied to the whole image, CSS is not aware of the transparency of your image and then it can't apply the shadow just to the actual not-transparent content of it. You should add a shadow in your image, on Photoshop (or your image-editing software).

Answer (score 1):

Because your png is setting its shadow based on the element which in your case is an image of x/y dimension (a box). It doesn't know to recognize the cutoff lines, apply the shadow to the image itself instead as part of the image.

Answer (score 1):

It still is transparent if you see the left side of the image where the blue background appears.

[image]

The shadow on the bottom left just makes it look like there is a border.

If you want a shadow on the actual "sign" you should add that in your image editor

Answer (score 0):

The dropshadow is applied to the dimensions of the image regardless of transparency.